# Adding item to observablearray from a dropdown box using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have two observablearrays in my ViewModel:

- ShortlistedCountries
- CompanyMainList

All companies names are displayed in a dropdown box. And the shortlisted companies are listed underneath it.

I would like to achieve two things from this demo.

Firstly, the users should be able to select the company name from the dropdown and add it to the Shortlisted company list.

Secondly, the users should get an error message (or alert) if they try to shortlist a company that has already been added to the shortlisted companies list.

Please have a look at my demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnmh79yk/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>All Companies</div>
    <div>
        <div id="rdoCompanyServer">
            <select data-bind="options:CompanyMainList, optionsText:'CompanyName', optionsValue:'id', optionsCaption: 'Select a company...'"></select>  <a href="#" data-bind="click:AddToShortlistedCountries">Add to Shortlist</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
    <div id="sectionHeading">My Shortlisted Companies</div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <ol data-bind="foreach: ShortlistedCountries">
                <li><span data-bind="text:CompanyName"></span><span id="removeshortlist">
                             <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.DeleteShortlistedCountries">Remove</a></span>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Knockout JS**

```
function CompanyViewModel() {
   var self = this;

   self.currentDemoLicenses = ko.pureComputed(function () {
       return self.demoLicenses().length;
   });




   /* adding bookmark servers in the same view TEST */

   self.bookmarkedServerCount = ko.pureComputed(function () {
       return self.ShortlistedCountries().length;
   });

   self.ShortlistedCountries = ko.observableArray([{
       CompanyName: 'Apple Inc',
       id: 11
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'TDK',
       id: 15
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Samsung',
       id: 16
   }

   ]);

   self.DeleteShortlistedCountries = function (ShortlistedCountries) {
       self.ShortlistedCountries.remove(ShortlistedCountries);
   };


   self.AddToShortlistedCountries = function () {
       self.ShortlistedCountries.push(self.ShortlistedCountries);
   };


   self.CompanyMainList = ko.observableArray([{
       CompanyName: 'Acer',
       id: 1
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Toshiba',
       id: 12
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Sony',
       id: 13
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'LG',
       id: 14
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'HP',
       id: 6
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Hitachi',
       id: 6
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Apple Inc',
       id: 11
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'TDK',
       id: 15
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Samsung',
       id: 16
   }, {
       CompanyName: 'Panasonic',
       id: 7
   }]);
};


$(document).ready(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new CompanyViewModel());

});
```

Have a look at my demo in     [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnmh79yk/5/)

Please let me know if I am missing some thing or is there anything wrong with my code.

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

**ViewModel:**

```
       function CompanyViewModel() {
           var self = this;
           self.selectedCompany = ko.observable();//has dropdown selection

           self.ShortlistedCompanies = ko.observableArray([{
               CompanyName: 'Apple Inc',
               id: 11
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'TDK',
               id: 15
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Samsung',
               id: 16
           }

           ]);

           var isExists = function (data) { //function checks for duplicates
               var status = false;
               ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ShortlistedCompanies(), function (item) {
                   if (item.id === data.id) {
                       status = true;
                       return status;
                   }
               });
               return status;
           }

           self.DeleteShortlistedCompanies = function (ShortlistedCompanies) {
               self.ShortlistedCompanies.remove(ShortlistedCompanies);
           };


           self.AddToShortlistedCompanies = function () {
               if (!self.selectedCompany()) {
                   alert('select something');
                   return;
               }
               if (isExists(self.selectedCompany())) {
                   alert('Cannot add duplicates');
                   return;
               }
               self.ShortlistedCompanies.push(self.selectedCompany());
           };
           self.CompanyMainList = ko.observableArray([{
               CompanyName: 'Acer',
               id: 1
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Toshiba',
               id: 12
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Sony',
               id: 13
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'LG',
               id: 14
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'HP',
               id: 6
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Hitachi',
               id: 6
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Apple Inc',
               id: 11
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'TDK',
               id: 15
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Samsung',
               id: 16
           }, {
               CompanyName: 'Panasonic',
               id: 7
           }]);
       };
```

**View :**

```
 <div id="rdoCompanyServer">
        <select data-bind="options:CompanyMainList, optionsText:'CompanyName', optionsCaption: 'Select a company...',value:selectedCompany"></select>   <a href="#" data-bind="click:AddToShortlistedCompanies">Add to Shortlist</a>
 </div>
```

For reference working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/cnmh79yk/7/)**

Comment: Thank you soo much! you are definitely 'super cool'. It was very helpful. Thank you once again :) God bless

Comment: glad it helps . don't forget to mark it as answer(so someone can refer to this later)

Comment: Thank you supercool, I just marked your reply as 'answered'. Can I have a request, could you please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466073/showing-modal-light-box-to-display-items-using-knockout-js

If you could kindly help, that would be great.

Best regards.